# Does this exist - 'screwdriver gun' with cartridge to automatically load new screws?

Tags: screws, screwdriver

I'm looking to do some really repetitive assembly that involves screw-driving a ton of M2 screws over and over again into threaded holes to put two plastic pieces together.

Because it's a high volume job, I want to find the right tool. I thought it would be so awesome if there was a one handed electric screwdriver of some sort that would dispense the M2 screw as I hold the button, then once it's in the threaded hole/fully dispensed a new one pops out of the gun, and I can move onto the next hole, etc.

Found some related stuff for nails obviously, which is good for woodworking but not exactly my application:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Woodworking-decoration-chain-with-screw-gun-professional-automatic-screw-driver-decorating-tools-220V-780W-1PC/32832683890.html

Could anyone confirm if what I'm looking for exists, and point me to some example products? Also down to modify similar existing tools to suit my application if need be. Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of systems that auto-feed collated screws -- dedicated screwguns, attachments for screwguns, attachments for drills, etc. But everything I've ever seen has been tailored for the construction industry. The available screws were things like drywall or deck screws. I don't recall ever seeing anything for machine screws. When I worked in industry, one company had machinists who cobbled together custom assembly equipment that singulated and fed loose machine screws from a hopper to a driver via a track or channel. You may need to make your own feeder or collate your own screws.

Comment: Would you be able to use self tapping screws instead of machine screws?

Comment: The application is currently calling for machine screws

Comment: Should it match up the threads, or just power through and strip the threads out if it doesn't line up initially? Would you consider using automotive grade screws with features to prevent that?

Comment: @Harper I'm looking for something simpler that just does the job, I suppose the second option is fine. Sure I'd consider that - whatever does it!